# RequireJs text plugin and UnderscoreJs templates

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, requirejs-text

Alright people,

I am using the RequireJs text plugin to pull in underscore templates (.html) in my backbone application. Unfortunately my underscore code in my templates are being rendered as plain text.

```
define(['Backbone', 'text!Templates/BlogIndex.html', 'text!Templates/Elements/Blog/List.html'], function(Backbone, Template, ElementList){

var BlogPostIndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
       this.template = _.template($(Template).html(), {posts : this.collection});
       this.render();

    },

    render: function (Template) {
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        return this;
    }

});

return BlogPostIndexView;
```

});

Here is my code for my view, you can see i am pulling-in two templates and setting them. However it getting rendered as ...

```
Globall Coach Blog Posts

<% _.each(posts, function(post){ %>
<%= _.escape(post.title) %>
<% }); %>
```

Has anybody ever had this issue?

Comment: Doesn't `text!...` give you the text so you'd just need to say `_.template(Template)`? And `_.template(tmpl, date)` doesn't work as of Underscore 1.7.0, you need to `t = _.template(tmpl); h = t(data)` now.

Comment: Thanks looks like i am getting somewhere now dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns @mu-is-to-short was correct, requireJs text module returns the the raw html.

Here it `define(['Backbone', 'text!Templates/BlogIndex.html', 'text!Templates/Elements/Blog/List.html'], function(Backbone, Template, ElementList){

```
var BlogPostIndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
       this.template = _.template(Template);

    },

    render: function (Template) {
        this.$el.html(this.template({posts : this.collection.toJSON()}));
        return this;
    }

});

return BlogPostIndexView; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're not using the underscore template function correctly.  Underscore compiles the string into a function in which you can pipe in data.  so your code should look like this:

```
define(['Backbone', 'text!Templates/BlogIndex.html', 'text!Templates/Elements/Blog/List.html'], function(Backbone, Template, ElementList){

var BlogPostIndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
       this.template = _.template($(Template).html())({posts : this.collection});
       this.render();

    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        return this;
    }

});

return BlogPostIndexView;
```

But I would refactor this further because you usually want to dynamically re-render with the latest data so I would put the piping in the data to the template in the "render" method instead of "initialize".

So preferably I would do this:

```
define(['Backbone', 'text!Templates/BlogIndex.html', 'text!Templates/Elements/Blog/List.html'], function(Backbone, Template, ElementList){

var BlogPostIndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
       this.template = _.template($(Template).html())
       this.render();

    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template({posts : this.collection}));
        return this;
    }

});

return BlogPostIndexView;
```